# Is Nginx's approach to CPUs scalability (per process epoll event queue) optimal?

Tags: linux, nginx, linux-kernel, network-programming, scalability

Nginx's approach to CPUs scalability is based on the creation of the number of almost independent processes each owning an event queue and then using SO_REUSEPORT to spread incoming connections, IRQs, NIC packets over all cores relatively evenly.

Does it lead to better scalability (fewer kernel data sharing = fewer locks) than creating only **one Linux process** followed by the creation of array of threads still equal to the number of CPUs and a per thread event queue in every thread?

Here is an example of Nginx scaling up to around 32 CPUs. Disabled HT and overall number of 36 real cores could be the main reason for this, as well as relative NICs saturation or even cores GHz drop due to overheating:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/testing-the-performance-of-nginx-and-nginx-plus-web-servers/

Also: https://dzone.com/articles/inside-nginx-how-we-designed

Comment: Why do you think "fewer kernel data sharing" implies better scalability in the first place?

Comment: Because sharing rw data/queues is the first factor to limit scalability over 100+ CPUs

Comment: Oh, so by "scalability" you mean in the number of CPUs, not in the number of connections or network throughput. I think you should clarify this by editing the post.

Comment: Edited. I'am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, purely asynchronous calls in a situation where you don't use (red) threads and don't need to share data would be better than using (red) threads because you will avoid the context switching overhead that forces you to bounce in and out of the kernel just to switch to another thread. You may also be less likely to get contention (threads can accidentally share something internal such as a cache-line).

In reality it could go either way depending on the program in question the vagaries of the programming language, the kernel, whether the threads were red or green, the hardware, the task, skill of the programmer etc.

Coming back to your original question NGINX's approach is going to be good and the overheads are going to be low (contrast it with Apache for example). For pure "packet pushing" it's an excellent low overhead approach but you may find a tradeoff when it comes to flexibility. It's also worth noting [NGINX can spin up a worker per core](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html?#worker_processes) so at that point it can reap the benefits of affinity (less data moving because everything is hopefully local) while still being lower overhead...

Depending on where the data is coming from and going you can likely best NGINX in specific scenarios (e.g. by using something like DPDK) or using technology built around techniques like `io-uring` but perhaps at some point in the future NGINX itself will adopt such technology...

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like we can get hard data to answer this question by comparing Nginx to Envoy Proxy because it uses the [architecture](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/intro/threading_model) you are curious about:

> Envoy uses a single process with multiple threads architecture. A single master thread controls various sporadic coordination tasks while some number of worker threads perform listening, filtering, and forwarding

While they were initially developed years apart to solve different problems, they currently have extremely similar capabilities and are often compared against one another.

Looking at one such [comparison](https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-5-popular-load-balancers-nginx-haproxy-envoy-traefik-and-alb/), Envoy showed better throughput and latency. Another [comparison](https://www.getambassador.io/resources/envoyproxy-performance-on-k8s/) has Ambassador (based on Envoy) vs Nginx, and again Envoy shows better results.

Given this data, I'd say that yes the Single Process, Event-Loop and Thread Pool model (Envoy) seems to scale better than multiple processes with shared-IPC model (Nginx).

Comment: Not a convincing benchmark - seems nginx is behind mainly due to the business logic implementation, not server core logic - the latency should be in tens of ms in both tests at most and grow very slow with every new CPU core. Also nginx IPC is basically mapped memory sharing.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it lead to better scalability (fewer kernel data sharing = fewer locks) than creating only one Linux process followed by the creation of array of threads still equal to the number of CPUs and a per thread event queue in every thread?

From [The SO_REUSEPORT socket option](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/) article:

> The first of the traditional approaches is to have a single listener thread that accepts all incoming connections and then passes these off to other threads for processing. **The problem with this approach is that the listening thread can become a bottleneck in extreme cases.** In early discussions on `SO_REUSEPORT`, Tom noted that he was dealing with applications that accepted 40,000 connections per second.